# get_field() return old values

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a problem with get_field(). This function doesn't return the last inserted value with previously created fields. If i create a new field, get_field() doesn't return any value. All the value are correctly stored on database. What could be the problem? 
I have ACF 5.8.0 and Wordpress 5.2.

EDIT

```
<?php /* Template Name: Chi Siamo */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php $address_map = get_field('indirizzo_mappa'); ?>

<div id="aboutUs" class="container">

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="title">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

</div>

<?php if ($address_map) : ?>
<h1 class="mapTitle"><?php echo __('WHERE WE ARE','noisegallery'); ?></h1>
<div id="map" data-address="<?php echo $address_map; ?>"></div>
<?php endif;?>

<div class="firma">Designed from scratch by <b><a target="_blank" href="http://hellodude.it">DUDE</a></b></div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons (apart from cache not being cleared) is duplicated `field_xxx` post_name rows in `wp_posts` table. The reason is usually connected with exporting/importing fields or db changes during major plugin update (at least some users reported that).

When it happens, you get values from latest post in wp-admin and in `acf/save_post` hook, but when you're trying to `get_field` you get only values from oldest post of the same `field_xxx`.

You can easily check if that's the case with following query:

```
select post_name, count(ID) c, group_concat(ID) 
from wp_posts 
where post_type='acf-field'
group by post_name
having c>1;
```

If there are any values in results it's problably it. You can safely remove duplicated values starting from oldest post.

**Of course you should create backup before doing that - export all acf fields to json file and make a dump od database.**

In case there are many of them you can use this script which will leave highest ID of each duplicate fields and remove all duplicates.

```php
include_once "wp-config.php";
include_once "wp-includes/wp-db.php";

$query = "select post_name, count(ID) c, group_concat(ID) gc from wp_posts where post_type='acf-field'
group by post_name
having c>1;";

$rows = $wpdb->get_results($query);

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $duplicatedIds = explode(',', $row['gc']);

    $highestId = max($duplicatedIds);

    $keyToPreserve = array_search($highestId, $duplicatedIds);

    unset($duplicatedIds[$keyToPreserve]);

    $toRemoveIds = implode(',', $duplicatedIds);

    echo "- Removing duplicated posts from field {$row['post_name']}: $toRemoveIds. Preserving {$highestId}.\n";

    foreach ($duplicatedIds as $postId) {
        wp_delete_post($postId);
    }
}

wp_cache_flush();
```

After removing duplicated rows from database problem should not exist anymore.
If you're using W3 Cache or any other cache plugin, you should purge it's cache as well.

Answer (score 0):

`get_field('yourFieldName')` needs to be echoed and as I have done here include a field name to get the value from.

You can also use `the_field('yourFieldName') without adding`echo`.  See the examples below:

Using `get_field()`:

`<h2><?php echo get_field('yourFieldName'); ?></h2>`

Using `the_field()`:

`<h2><?php the_field('yourFieldName'); ?></h2>`

Comment: Yeah, that’s what i am doing. For example, i used get_field('indirizzo_mappa') but the returned value is an old value attributed to 'indirizzo_mappa' and not the last entered. (Note that in Wordpress’s backend, the field shows the right/last value)

Comment: Ok, can you share the code you are using for your loop??  Are you starting the loop with the first post?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use get_field in while loop. Some time the post ID does not pass properly when we use get_field() function out side while loop or without postID parameter.

```
<?php /* Template Name: Chi Siamo */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="aboutUs" class="container">

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="title">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
<?php $address_map = get_field('indirizzo_mappa'); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

</div>

<?php if ($address_map) : ?>
  <h1 class="mapTitle"><?php echo __('WHERE WE ARE','noisegallery'); ?></h1>
  <div id="map" data-address="<?php echo $address_map; ?>"></div>
<?php endif;?>

<div class="firma">Designed from scratch by <b><a target="_blank" href="http://hellodude.it">DUDE</a></b></div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```